# OCILogon failure for OCI_UTF16 enviornment

Tags: c, oracle10g, oracle-call-interface

The OCILogon function says username ,password and database parameters must be in UTF-16 encoding in OCI_UTF16 environment mode. I am passing these parameters as follows,

```
OCILogon(p_env, p_err, &p_svc,"scott", 5,"tiger",5,"test" , 4);
```

Please let me know how to pass in UTF_16 format. Do I have to use OCI_ATTR_CHARSET_ID and set it to OCI_UTF16?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, Oracle [documentation says](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96584/oci15re9.htm) that it :

> Must be in UTF-16 encoding in OCI_UTF16 environment mode.

In order to convert it to UTF-16, they don't say it here but Oracle provides a simple macro.
It should be as simple as this :

```
rc = OCILogon(p_env, p_err, &p_svc, UTF16("scott"), 5, UTF16("tiger"), 5, UTF16("d458_nat"), 8);
```

Documentation [claims too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10764/globalization.htm#LNCPP20419) that you can also use a "L" in order to use widestring literal, so this should also works :

```
 rc = OCILogon(p_env, p_err, &p_svc, L"scott", 5, L"tiger", 5, L"d458_nat", 8);
```

NB: You should include ocilib.h and link with ocilibw.Lib, as stated by oci documentation :

> On Microsoft Windows, 32bits and 64bits (x86) DLLs are provided and
>   can be easily recompiled. Unpack the current archive (ocilib-xyz-windows.zip)
>   Copy ocilib\include\ocilib.h
>   Copy ocilib\lib32 |64\ocilib [x].Lib
>   Copy ocilib\lib32|64\ocilib [x]. Dll [...]
>   Where [x] is the compiled version of OCILIB ('a'> -> ANSI, 'w' -> Unicode, 'm' -> Mixed)

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. I tried using the UTF macro to convert to Unicode but its giving me linking error. Do I have to add any libraries or include header file to support this macro in my code.My code is built using OCI.lib.

Comment: @user1268935 see my completed answer

Comment: I have included the DLLs and LIB from ocilib-3.9.3-windows.zip.error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _UTF16 referenced in function _main  
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Comment: I have used OCIlibm library. I tried using L for widestring literal rc = OCILogon(p_env, p_err, &p_svc, L"scott", 5, L"tiger", 5, L"d458_nat", 8); However, logon was not established for UTF16 enviornment. For UTF16 macro, Error "'UTF16': identifier not found" is thrown. rc = OCILogon(p_env, p_err, &p_svc, UTF16("scott"), 5, UTF16("tiger"), 5, UTF16("d458_nat"), 8); I also tried OCICharSetToUnicode and OCINlsCharSetConvert to convert the data into UTF16 encoding mode. However, I even failed there to establish connection with database when OCIEnvNlsCreate creates UTF16 enviornmant mode.@Coren